# How to achieve hierarchical data binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, hierarchical

Learning WPF here and I'm trying to get my head around hierarchical data binding.

This is my situation:

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { ... }
    public IEnumerable<B> Children { ... }
}

public class B
{
    public string SomeValue { ... }
}
```

I want to use a `ItemsControl` to display a collection of `A` and for each occurance of `A` I want an inner `ItemsControl` to display `A.Children`.

I thought this would do the trick but, apparently, I have much to learn yet...

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icCollectionOfAs" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="auto" Height="auto">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" />
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeValue}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Then, in code-behind...

```
icCollectionOfAs.ItemsSource = createSomeAsWithChildBsInThem();
```

The result of all this is nothing gets shown. Why?

Thanks

Comment: do you set this before or after the screen is first displayed?  `icCollectionOfAs.ItemsSource = createSomeAsWithChildBsInThem();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not specify the ItemsSource both in XAML (`ItemsSource="{Binding}"`) and code behind (`icCollectionOfAs.ItemsSource = createSomeAsWithChildBsInThem();`) the XAML might have been called later.

The rest seems fine to me except that the TextBlock for the ID will probably be hidden behind the ItemsControl for the children as you use a Grid without rows or columns rather than a StackPanel.

Comment: Ok, seems I'm not as far off target as I first believed. This is my status atm:
1. The A.Id property is indeed rendered (thanks for point out the need for rows) so apparently the binding works at the first level (A).
2. I still don't see any children rendered (B.SomeValue) so the second level is either not bound correctly or there's some problem while rendering B.SomeValue.

Comment: Just a question pertaining to this: As I understand it: ItemsSource="{Binding}" means I need to set the control's DataContext, right?

Comment: It does not mean that you need to set the DataContext, the DataContext could also be inherited, all that statement means is that you bind to the DataContext, it does not entail any imperative.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was: ItemsSource _is_ the ItemsControl's DataContext so it needs to be assigned somehow, right?

Anyway, the actual mistake I did in all this was in the object model. My objects did not inherit from DependencyObjects and thwir properties weren't Dependency Properties.

Comment: I would not suggest that your objects inherit from DepedencyObject, it has some downsides to it, mainly thread-affinity. Your object-model normally works using the binding-enabling interfaces, like [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip there H.B.